# Highcharts overflowing parent div Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

The highcharts-container div that gets generated is always a constant 600x400 in size and overflows my bootstrap divs.

I enabled chart.reflow to true, even though it should be on by default, and that also did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/149

I can't be 100% sure because I haven't seen your code, but it should be fixed by calling the `chart.reflow()` method. To call it you need access to the `chart` object. You can just call it in the `ChartCallbackFunction` the only thing is that it needs to be called after the chart gets rendered, that's why you need to wrap it within `setTimeout()`

```js
 chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction = function (chart): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            chart.reflow();
        },0);
    }
```

```html
<highcharts-chart 
     [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
     [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
     [options]="chartOptions"
></highcharts-chart>
```